# ASP Core Cache SQL Data in Memory to Query with Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a static SQL dataset that I want to store in memory and query from one controller. For example

```
var dataRecords = dataList.Where(dl => dl.Contains(x.ToString());
```

With Core 2.1, I am not sure how to do this?

If I create a private list in the controller will that persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers are instantiated and disposed with each request, so setting something on your controller will not persist to the next request. You should use `IDistributedCache`. It's as simple as injecting that into your controller:

```
private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;

public FooController(IDistributedCache cache)
{
    _cache = cache ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cache));
}
```

Then, you just use methods off that like `GetAsync` and `SetAsync` to get/set values in the cache, respectively. By default, ASP.NET Core will satisfy the dependency with `MemoryDistributedCache`, which is fine for development, but you'll want to utilize something like Redis or SQL Server as your backing store in production.

This is all clearly [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.1).